# Sanity groc filter query using reference

Tags: sanity, groc

I have a sanity project where I have a page builder approach, one of my blocks is a archive block which will show a selection of posts. Within the block I have the option to choose categories and tags. If a category or tags is selected then only post assiged to either of those should be returned.

I have this groc query

```
*[_type == "page" && slug.current == $slug][0]{
  ...,
  _id,
  _createdAt,
  "slug": slug.current,
  "meta": seo.meta,
  title,
  blocks[]{
    ...,
    (_type == "hero")=>{
      content{
        text[]{
          ...
        }
      },
      image{
        ...,
        "id": asset._ref,
        "preview": asset->metadata.lqip,
        hotspot { x, y },
        crop { bottom, left, right, top },
        overlay
      }
    },
    (_type == "content")=>{
      ...,
      "columns": content
    },
    (_type == "archive")=>{
      "foo": categories[0]._ref,
      "posts": *[_type == "post" && references(categories[0]._ref)]
    }
  }
}
```

The issue I face is that all posts are return not just the ones with the selected category.

This is the data being returned, you can see my "foo" has the ref but when passed into the reference function doesn't work. If I hard code the value it does.

```
blocks:[…] 4 items
  0:{…} 5 properties
  1:{…} 4 properties
  2:{…} 5 properties
  3:{…} 7 properties
    foo:81890473-8865-4ded-bcb8-f95b7c371011
    posts:[…] 4 items
      0:{…} 10 properties
      1:{…} 10 properties
      2:{…} 10 properties
      3:{…} 10 properties
    categories:[…] 1 item
      0:{…} 7 properties
        _createdAt:2023-12-13T20:53:37Z
        _rev:m8VOqhccr4TPWaaeSMEqMW
        _type:category
        name:Macro Matters
        _id:81890473-8865-4ded-bcb8-f95b7c371011
        _updatedAt:2023-12-14T09:39:36Z
        slug:{…} 2 properties
        _key:c2dcd177b0e4
    tags:[…] 1 item
      0:{…} 3 properties
     _type:archive
  invertBackground:false
_type:page
_id:41353910-e3f9-4bbf-9c49-f0d24bcd991a
title:Home
_updatedAt:2023-12-14T16:34:46Z
_createdAt:2023-12-12T19:49:23Z
_rev:ZthcaWUJAg6CELweYqf6vl
slug:/
meta:{…} 3 properties
seo:{…} 1 property
```

Any ideas how I can get this working if I have a category selected?